# nextgen pro horizontal filmstrip moves up as browser narrows

Tags: responsive, plugin-nextgen-gallery

[Here's](http://www.kwdesigns.com/wordpress/coastal-elegance) the site...

I'm trying to keep the top of the images in my slideshow at the same height.

But as I make my browser narrower, the images and thumbnails move higher and higher.

The movement is gradual, not all at once, so I suspect it is correlated with the viewport width.

I've tried adjusting CSS but nothing I can find seems to control the creeping height.

Appreciate any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that various elements are having their height set dynamically via javascript, when the viewport width changes. This would probably override any css settings you've set. Looking at the code, there's an embedded iframe, within which there's javascript like this:

```
var calculateHeight = function (settings) { ...
```

The code then calculates a height to use based on the viewport width. You'll need to look at disabling/modifying that javascript.